# Drag and drop functionality of android

Tags: android

Am working on implementing the Drag and Drop functionality in android
Here is my code.

```
  public class DragnDropActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,OnDragListener 
{
}
```

am unable to reach onDraw call back function

Comment: Can you please give a bit more details regarding this.

Comment: The problem is that i am not able to enter the onDrag callback

Comment: Thanks for upvote my answer if you use this another time then upvote this another time ok thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1):

OnDragListener since API level 11. Check your API level.

Comment: The problem is that i am not able to enter the onDrag callback.I am Using SDK16

Comment: I was talking about Android SDK, not Java SDK

Comment: Yes,i mwntioned the same android sdk r16...I am using it

Answer (score 1):

OnDragListener can be implemented using android 3 i.e API Level 11 and higher versions. 
If u have api level 11 sdks installed then change android build path to android 3 API 11 version.